# ScrollView moves content over when scrolling

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using a `ScrollViewReader` that is passed to another view, the views content moves over when scrolling. If the `ForEach` is inside the same view as the reader the view shift does not happen. When you manually scroll the views fix themselves. I have posted a simplified version below.

How would I stop the view from shifting over when the view is being scrolled?

I am using Xcode13 beta 5

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                    Button("Scroll to bottom") {
                        withAnimation {
                            proxy.scrollTo(99, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    }
                    TestView(proxy: proxy)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var proxy: ScrollViewProxy
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {            ForEach(1..<100) { index in
                Text("Test \(index)")
                    .id(index)
            }
            Button("Scroll to top") {
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .top)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: A ForEach would have to always be in the same view as the proxy? In the specific scenario the TestView would be a view that is used on multiple pages hence the extraction to a separate view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the views to scroll to, nested in another view.

#### Solution #1

Remove the `VStack`:

```
struct TestView: View {
    let proxy: ScrollViewProxy

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(1..<100) { index in
            Text("Test \(index)")
                .id(index)
        }

        Button("Scroll to top") {
            withAnimation {
                proxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .top)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Solution #2

Give the extracted view the content at the top of the `ScrollView`, by passing it in:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestView { proxy in
                Button("Scroll to bottom") {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(99, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder let content: (ScrollViewProxy) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                content(proxy)

                ForEach(1..<100) { index in
                    Text("Test \(index)")
                        .id(index)
                }

                Button("Scroll to top") {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I would recommend a slightly different way of doing this. If possible, it is probably best to have this in just one view. However, you want to reuse some of the components so this may not be what you are looking for.

Another thing I noticed: the scrolling doesn't go far enough to reach the buttons, which can appear underneath the safe-area and unable to be pressed. Make these changes:

```
Button("Scroll to bottom") {
    withAnimation {
        proxy.scrollTo("bottom", anchor: .bottom)
    }
}
.id("top")
```

```
Button("Scroll to top") {
    withAnimation {
        proxy.scrollTo("top", anchor: .top)
    }
}
.id("bottom")
```

Comment: I have tried multiple different ways and the only option really is to never have any view that you intend to scroll to nested like you said in the solution one. So if the view to be shared happens to be a complicated view with many parts it would be impossible unless you make invisible views outside the nested parts just for the point of making anchor points to scroll to?

Comment: @runemonster Yep - from the sounds of it, seems like you'll just need a `ZStack` with the invisible views underneath, aligned to the real views. The thing is, when you wrap a `VStack`, those 100 or whatever `id`s don't work because a view (the `VStack` in this case) can only have a single `id`. That's why it makes _sense_ why it doesn't work. I really don't understand why Apple used `id(_:)` rather than `tag(_:)`... but I guess that's something we'll never know the answer to. I don't know if that would be too different anyway either.